# multiple django projects in one server using gunicorn and nginx with only ip and ports

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, server, gunicorn

I want to ask about deploying multiple django projects in one remote server using gunicorn and nginx. I've learnt that for each project I should create `.socket` and `.service` files and also configure nginx. All tutorials and videos I've seen showed project with domains, like (`project1.example.com`, `project2.example.com`). I did it once it works perfectly for domains. But what if I want to deploy them just using IP address and port for now, like (project1 in `12.34.56.78:8000`, project2 in `12.34.56.78:8001`.) I don't have domain and let's say I don't want it right now. Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend using supervisor to handle many projects on one server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already set up multiple projects and created separate sockets for each of them. You need to configure nginx to listen to different ports and redirect each of them to the correct socket.

Here's a sample nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 12.34.56.78;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/project1;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/project1.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8001;
    server_name 12.34.56.78;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/project2;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/project2.sock;
    }
}
```